# Android activity name defined in Manifest.xml

Tags: android

I have an Activity defined in my manifest as:

```
<activity
android:name=".userhistory.UserHistory"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:label="User History">
</activity>
```

Now i want to get the `value` of the `label` attribute from within my activity code.

Is there any way i can do this ?

Comment: you can define your string in string.xml and from there you can read...

Comment: @visheshchandra That won't work, there is no way of knowing the "android:label" from the strings.xml, unless he hardcodes a string like "appname", but why do that when there's api's for retreiving information from the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

"Pseudo"-code:

```
PackageManager PM = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
PackageInfo PI = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String strLabel = PI.applicationInfo.loadLabel(PM).toString();
```

`strLabel` will contain the value in `android:label` from your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

use string.xml to save your all string like following

```
<resources>
<string name="activity_name">User History</string>
</resources>
```

then use it any where in your other xml like this

.android:label="@string/activity_name"

and you can use it in activity like this

```
 String activityname= getString(R.string.activity_name);
```

Comment: That's not what he asked for.

Comment: Its very simple MyActivity.this.getTitle()